# Решить дифференциальные уравнения высших порядков, допускающие понижение порядка

Tags: математика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь решать разные варианты заданий по дифф. уравнением. Попадаются подобные уравнения высшего порядка(частное решение искать не нужно), однако здесь нет иксов и `y` без штриха... Пытался делать замену, ничего не выходит. Подскажите алгоритм решения подобных задач.

Comment: У вас же нет x! делайте замену `y' = p(y)`, `y''=p*dp/dy` - и вперед! Сводите к уравнению первого порядка, потом, найдя его решение - решаете подстановку.

Comment: Так я и говорю, что у меня нет x. Но эту замену уже делал и не ничего путного не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да ну как ничего не получается! Такие дифуры в 9 классе решать надо уметь...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Коэффициенты сами вычислить сумеете или это тоже непосильный интеллектуальный подвиг?

Comment: Уже решил как раз до того, как отправили решение
Но все равно благодарю :) Отмечаю как правильное.

Comment: Быстрее было бы, если бы за тебя прорешали и всё, а так мозг ленится.